# Data Copy using Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a folder of 10 excel-based CSV files. Is there any method to copy the data from all these files into 1 excel

Not good with VBA, so thought to ask you guys

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Questions like this were asked at least 100 times here on Stack Overflow. Please do some research and try something on your own. Then come beack with your code and ask a question to it. • Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

On a first sight, I would go for the following approach (coming up with the codes is up to you, Google is your friend):

- Get a list of all file names within that directory
- Iterate over every item from the above list and open the file with `Workbooks.Open(...)`
- Copy the whole content and paste it to the additional Excel you want to manage to hold the data of all files
- Repeat the steps for each file

Remember to save the last row after every paste s.t. you can continue with amending the data into the addtional Excel instead of replacing the content.